# How to set environment variables in docker run

Tags: node.js, docker

I'm trying to set environment variables in my docker run command.

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:8.16.0-alpine

WORKDIR /Users/Marc/Dev/GreenPool/docker-test

COPY test.js ./

COPY . .

RUN ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node

ENTRYPOINT ["node", "./test.js", "data"]
```

and here is my command:

```
docker run marcvander/node-test:latest -e "data=2"
```

The console output:

```
Undefined
NaN
NaN
```

If I set the environment variable in my Dockerfile, it works:

```
ENV data=3
```

The console output:

```
3
3
6
```

My test.js file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

var data = process.env.data;
console.log(data);
data = Number(data);

function addTwoNumbers(data) {
  console.log(data);
  console.log(data + data);
  return data + data;
}

addTwoNumbers(data);
```

Comment: Have you tried `docker run -e "data=2" marcvander/node-test:latest`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe It works! Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-e` flag needs to be before the image name.

To emulate your `ENTRYPOINT`ed Dockerfile:

```
$ docker run -it --entrypoint=printenv ubuntu:16.04 -e foo=bar
printenv: invalid option -- 'e'
```

c.f.

```
$ docker run -it --entrypoint=printenv -e foo=bar ubuntu:16.04
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
HOSTNAME=0d4ef96a831d
TERM=xterm
foo=bar
HOME=/root
```